# Converting ActiveMQ bean to Camel Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel

This is the given route of the ActiveMQ in the camel.

```
<route id="readInactiveRecordNotification">
        <from uri="appActiveMQConsumer:queue:Consumer.hydra.ldap_updates_poller.VirtualTopic.ldap.in" />
```

The Bean is given below:

```
   @Bean(name = "appActiveMQConsumer")
    public ActiveMQComponent amqConsumer() throws Exception {
        ActiveMQComponent amqConsumer = new ActiveMQComponent();
        amqConsumer.setConnectionFactory(pooledConnectionFactoryConsumer());
        amqConsumer.setTransacted(true);
        amqConsumer.setDeliveryPersistent(true);
        amqConsumer.setCacheLevelName("CACHE_CONSUMER");
        amqConsumer.setAcknowledgementModeName("SESSION_TRANSACTED");
        return amqConsumer;
    }
}
```

I want to migrate this with Kafka. I have written the bean

```
 @Bean(name="appkafkaConsumer")
    public KafkaComponent kafkaComponentConsumer(){

        KafkaComponent kafkaComponentConsumer = new KafkaComponent();
        kafkaComponentConsumer.setConfiguration(kafkaConfiguration());
        return kafkaComponentConsumer;

    }
```

What is the correct way to migrate the above route?